# I want to set my FormsAuthentication cookie to timeout BUT VIA CODE

Tags: asp.net, security, forms-authentication

I want to set my FormsAuthentication cookie to timeout BUT VIA CODE. I know I can do this in the web.config but I want to configure at the database. Is this possible via code?

```
<system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
              <forms timeout="50000000"/>
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this you'll need to create your own [FormsAuthenticationTicket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx) and cookie and add it to the response manually.  See the example on the linked page.